# Selecting a random element in a category

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

Given a table in a PostgreSQL 11 database that resembles this:

```
CREATE TABLE yearly_urls ( year int, url varchar );
```

That has many thousands of rows of URLs over several years like this:

```
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ year | url       │
├──────┼───────────┤
│ 2009 │ /abc.jpeg │
│ 2009 │ /def.jpeg │
│ 2017 │ /ghi.jpeg │
│ 2018 │ /jkm.jpeg │
│ 2018 │ /nop.jpeg │
└──────┴───────────┘
```

What's the best way to write a query to retrieve a random URL for a given year?

In other words, one URL chosen at random for a given year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (year) year, url
from t
order by year, random();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct on` is very good. Also, you can use this query;

```
WITH year_urls_cte AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY year ORDER BY url DESC
  ) AS rn, year,url FROM yearly_urls order by random()
)
SELECT * FROM year_urls_cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY year;
```

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in the CTE version of the query as it does not produce a random URL per year on each invocation.  I went with the `distinct on` version.